# Is it possible to "steal" an onclick event handler from a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I have a button that was created dynamically after the DOM was loaded, it's part of a framework code so I can't change it and can't directly access that code.

This button has an on click event with internal state, I want to make another button later that will fire that same function.

If I add the same css classes as the original button to my button it doesn't work, probably because that button's onClick event isn't registered with jQuery but like this:

```
this.measureToolButton.onClick = function(e) {
        self.enableMeasureTool(!self.tool.isActive());
    };
```

So is there another way to "steal" that event from the original?

Comment: misleading question title - it sounded like you want to prevent the event from reaching the button (by stealing it) - what you want to do is _copy_ the event handler.

Comment: I can't copy that event handler as I said in the question. @Alnitak

Comment: if you can get a reference to `element.onclick` then you can copy the reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the new button to perform *exactly* as if the original button had been pressed, you can just trigger the old button's handler:

```
$('#newButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#oldButton').trigger('click');
});
```